# Error in converting JSON to Model : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

In my Flutter code, I am getting the following JSON input

```
{chat_mode: supplier, 
 last_message: Hello World, 
  members: {one: {name: yohan, photo: https://com/google.jpg, uid: qwer}, 
  two: {name: gayan, photo: https://ih1.u1.jpg, uid: abcd}}}
```

Actually this is data coming from Firebase Database. If i export the database it looks like this

```
"chat_room" : {
    "-MMbVLc0ucT4rck8zWGB" : {
      "chat_mode" : "supplier",
      "last_message" : "Hello World",
      "members" : {
        "one" : {
          "name" : "yohan",
          "photo" : "https://img-authors.flaticon.com/google.jpg",
          "uid" : "qwer"
        },
        "two" : {
          "name" : "gayan",
          "photo" : "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1057254628.1918/flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.u1.jpg",
          "uid" : "abcd"
        }
      }
    },
    "-MMbbviIhWjtXh5mwspG" : {
      "chat_mode" : "supplier",
      "last_message" : "Hello World",
      "members" : {
        "one" : {
          "name" : "yohan",
          "photo" : "https://img-authors.flaticon.com/google.jpg",
          "uid" : "K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaZJzPph2"
        },
        "two" : {
          "name" : "gayan",
          "photo" : "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1057254628.1918/flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.u1.jpg",
          "uid" : "K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaZJzPph2abcd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am using `Models` so the above structure was generated and saved in the database by them. Below are the models

**ChatRoomModel**

```
import 'chat_member_model.dart';

class ChatRoomModel {
    ChatRoomModel({
        this.chatMode,
        this.lastMessage,
        this.members,
        this.timestamp,
    });

    String chatMode;
    String lastMessage;
    Map<String, Member> members;
    int timestamp;

    factory ChatRoomModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChatRoomModel(
        chatMode: json["chat_mode"],
        lastMessage: json["last_message"],
        members: Map.from(json["members"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Member>(k, Member.fromJson(v))),
        timestamp: json["timestamp"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "chat_mode": chatMode,
        "last_message": lastMessage,
        "members": Map.from(members).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
        "timestamp": timestamp,
    };
}
```

**Member**

```
class Member {
    Member({
        this.name,
        this.photo,
        this.uid
    });

    String name;
    String photo;
    String uid;

    factory Member.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Member(
        name: json["name"],
        photo: json["photo"],
        uid: json["uid"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "photo": photo,
        "uid": uid,
    };
}
```

To read the incoming JSON from the server, I am using a `DataSnapshot` and try to convert it to Model. below is the code.

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

print(snapshot.value);
print("HERE WE GO!!");
ChatRoomModel chatRoomModel = ChatRoomModel.fromJson(convert.json.decode(snapshot.value));
```

Unfortunatly, this triggers the following error and I am unable to perform the conversion.

```
flutter: {chat_mode: supplier, last_message: Hello World, members: {one: {name: yohan, photo: https://img-authors.flaticon.com/google.jpg, uid: qwer}, two: {name: gayan, photo: https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1057254628.1918/flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.u1.jpg, uid: abcd}}}
flutter: HERE WE GO!!
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

I tried following as well, still not working

```
ChatRoomModel chatRoomModel = ChatRoomModel.fromJson(snapshot.value);
```

I get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `snapshot.value` is of type **Map**, and the parameter type required for the `convert.json.decode` method is of type **String**.

So, when you call convert.json.decode(snapshot. Value), the error type will be reported

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

You can try calling it like this:

```
ChatRoomModel chatRoomModel = ChatRoomModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value));
```

Comment: same error `E/flutter (12969): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: use `Map.castFrom`, on which line this is happenning? you might have to use this everywhere you have declared Map<String,dynamic> parameter,chatrrom, member